# How do you create variables in actions.class.php so that they are accessible in layout.php?

Tags: php, symfony1

In Symfony 1.2, how do you create variables in actions.class.php so that they are accessible in layout.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page has some information about it: http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/Symfony11LayoutUpgrade

It seems you can get the desired effect using this following code:

```
$this->getResponse()->setSlot('title', 'insert your title here');
```

And then use this in the layout file:

```
<title><?php echo get_slot('title') ?></title>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, by default, you can't, since it should be against the MVC pattern.

You should better pass variable to your view, but without using global (or kind of).